# How I do cancel inside CoroutineScope, and detect the cancellation

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Detect cancellation from CoroutineScope

I am trying to detect cancellation from CoroutineScope, but isCancelled property doesn't change when I trying to call cancel method inside CoroutineScope

Method I expected to cancel the Coroutine from ViewModel

```
fun login() = viewModelScope.launch{
        try{
            repository.login(emailLogin.get()!!, passwordLogin.get()!!)
        }catch (e: AuthenticationHttpErrorException){
            cancel(CancellationException(e.message))
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.e("ERROR LOGIN", e.message)
        }
    }
```

How I called the login method from Activity

```
fun submitLogin(view: View){
        val loginResult = authenticationViewModel.login()
        if(loginResult.isCancelled){
            Log.e("LOGIN FAILED", "Login cancelled")
        }else{
            Log.v("LOGIN SUCCESS", "Login success")
        }
    }
```

I am expecting **isCancelled** property change to true, when I called cancel method from CoroutineScope and Trigger some code inside if statement

Answer (score 1):

`launch` does start an asynchronous coroutine. Therefore the `login`-body will run later and you can't access the result directly after the invocation. 
In your example a simple `suspend` function may be better.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, can you show me example in code?

Answer (score 0):

You are canceling it on the `catch` block. Which means that 
 `repository.login(emailLogin.get()!!, passwordLogin.get()!!)` does not throw any exception. Or if it does, perhaps it is not the `AuthenticationHttpErrorException` that is being thrown. Just to check the error that is happening, try catching a general `Exception` and than handle the coroutine the same.So:

`catch (e: Exception)`